# Return value and the according text with javascript

Tags: javascript, text, return, var

I have this piece of code (it is part of a large javascript code) and I want it to return 'article' or 'articles' as well as the quantity.

If the var quantity = 1, it should return '1 article'.
If the var quantity = 0 or any other number, it should return 'x articles'

```
    quantity: function () {
                    var quantity = 0;
                    simpleCart.each(function (item) {
                        quantity += item.quantity();
                    });

                    return quantity;
                },
```

Can someone please show me how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I don't know how to do this. I'm new to javascript but i'm guessing that it has to do with an if statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simply ternary would work:

```
quantity: function () {
    var quantity = 0;
    simpleCart.each(function (item) {
        quantity += item.quantity();
    });

    return quantity + (quantity == 1 ? ' Article' : ' Articles');
};
```

As you've said you're new to JavaScript, the `?:` operator is basically a compact form of `if` in the form `expression ? when-true : when-false`.

Comment: Yeah I can see, wow that is handy. Thanks for the info, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
return quantity==undefined?'':quantity==1?'1 Article':quantity+' Articles';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
quantity: function () {
    var quantity = 0;
    simpleCart.each(function (item) {
        quantity += item.quantity();
    });

    return (quantity == 1) ? '1 article' : $quantity + ' articles';
}
```